# Joining two select queries

Tags: mysql

I want to join two select queries and don't know how to do it.

The first query gives me information on the invoice number, the client, the eventid and the amount that are all saved in the invoice table  :

```
SELECT invoice.Eventid, invoice.Invoiceno, 
event.clientid, client.clientid, clientname, gross_amount, VAT, total, due
FROM client, invoice, event, 
WHERE event.eventid=invoice.eventid and event.clientid = client.clientid group by invoice.eventid
```

The second query is checking the salary of the staffmember

```
SELECT event_ma.eventid, salary.staffid, SUM( cost_hour * TIME_TO_SEC( TIMEDIFF( hours, pause ) ) ) /3600 AS costs
FROM salary
JOIN event_ma ON salary.staffid = event_ma.staffid
GROUP BY event_ma.eventid
```

At the end I want to see the all relevant costs and income per event.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use this way:

```
CREATE VIEW `inv` AS
    SELECT invoice.Eventid AS inve, invoice.Invoiceno, 
    event.clientid, client.clientid, clientname, gross_amount, VAT, total, due
    FROM client, invoice, event, 
    WHERE event.eventid=invoice.eventid and event.clientid = client.clientid group by invoice.eventid

CREATE VIEW `ev` AS
    SELECT event_ma.eventid AS evee, salary.staffid, SUM( cost_hour * TIME_TO_SEC( TIMEDIFF( hours, pause ) ) ) /3600 AS costs
    FROM salary
    JOIN event_ma ON salary.staffid = event_ma.staffid
    GROUP BY event_ma.eventid
```

And your final query as:

```
SELECT * FROM `inv`, `ev`
    WHERE `inve` = `evee`;
```

Or you can also consider using MySQL `JOIN` this way:

```
SELECT * FROM `inv`
    JOIN `ev` ON `inv`.`inve` = `ev`.`evee`;
```

Comment: Why not use `JOIN` instead of `WHERE`?

Comment: @Vapire am not sure about the JOIN syntax. For this, JOIN is the right one.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand the question, you can take the first query, and then join the second query where the `eventID` matches. Also, just pointing out that you're using *old* join syntax in the first query - rather than using:

```
Select table1.col, table2.col From
table1, table2
...
```

You should use:

```
Select table1.col, table2.col From
table1 
INNER JOIN table2 On
table1.colID = table2.colID

...
```

And to answer your question:

```
SELECT invoice.eventid, 
       invoice.invoiceno, 
       event.clientid, 
       client.clientid, 
       clientname, 
       gross_amount, 
       vat, 
       total, 
       due 
FROM   client, 
       invoice, 
       event, 
       inner 
       JOIN (SELECT event_ma.eventid, 
                    salary.staffid, 
                    Sum(cost_hour * Time_to_sec(Timediff(hours, pause))) / 3600 
                    AS 
                          costs 
             FROM   salary 
                    JOIN event_ma 
                      ON salary.staffid = event_ma.staffid 
             GROUP  BY event_ma.eventid) x 
         ON invoice.eventid = x.eventid 
WHERE  event.eventid = invoice.eventid 
       AND event.clientid = client.clientid 
GROUP  BY invoice.eventid
```

Comment: However when I am using the above detailed query then Mysql complains that it doesn't know invoice.eventid in on clause

Comment: And the column costs in the inner join doesn't appear in the table

Comment: @SandraGrassl Change it to `Eventid` - I think that's how you have it in your original. I messed up when typing the query.

Comment: I have changed it to: Select * from(

SELECT invoice.eventid, 
       invoice.invoiceno, 
       event.clientid, 
       client.clientid, 
       clientname, 
       gross_amount, 
       vat, 
       total, 
       due 
FROM   client, 
       invoice, 
       event
WHERE  event.eventid = invoice.eventid 
       AND event.clientid = client.clientid) as Table1

Comment: inner 
       JOIN (SELECT event_ma.eventid, 
                    salary.staffid, 
                    Sum(cost_hour * Time_to_sec(Timediff(hours, pause))) / 3600 
                    AS 
                          costs 
             FROM   salary 
                    JOIN event_ma 
                      ON salary.staffid = event_ma.staffid 
             GROUP  BY event_ma.eventid) x
    
         ON table1.eventid = x.eventid 

GROUP  BY table1.eventid

Comment: But then I am getting only one column and the cost column is 0

Comment: so the query that I did mention on top did work. My dummydatabase did just not show any matching values. When changing it I was finally able to retrieve the data I wanted.

Comment: @SandraGrassl Great! So your original query worked the entire time?

Comment: No I mixed your query together with the comment from Barranka and then it worked. Select * from( SELECT invoice.eventid, invoice.invoiceno, event.clientid, client.clientid, clientname, gross_amount, vat, total, due FROM client, invoice, event WHERE event.eventid = invoice.eventid AND event.clientid = client.clientid) as Table1

Answer (score 0):

You can write a query that takes subqueries as data sources:

```
select ...
from 
    (select ...) as q1
    inner join (select ...) as q2 on ...
...
```